# What are the companies in the FTSE4Good UK 50?

Tags: united-kingdom, market-indexes, market-data, ethical-investing

I've been looking for a definitive and up-to-date (and reasonably regularly updated) source listing the companies included in the [FTSE4Good](https://www.theguardian.com/business/2001/jul/10/ftse.ethicalmoney1) UK 50 index (preferably by their LSE ticker code).

This has proven surprisingly hard to find.

Initially I assumed it'd be available at the [LSE's site](http://www.londonstockexchange.com/exchange/prices-and-markets/stocks/indices/ftse-indices.html) where lists of e.g [FTSE100 constituents](http://www.londonstockexchange.com/exchange/prices-and-markets/stocks/indices/summary/summary-indices-constituents.html?index=UKX) and [FTSE techmark constituents](http://www.londonstockexchange.com/exchange/prices-and-markets/stocks/indices/summary/summary-techmarkindices.html?index=TASX) can be found.  But while the FTSE4Good UK does [have a presence there](http://www.londonstockexchange.com/exchange/prices-and-markets/stocks/indices/ethic-indices/summary.html?index=I:4GUK), it's missing the "constituents" tab the other indices provide.

The other obvious place is the FTSE Russell's [own info on the index](http://www.ftse.com/products/indices/FTSE4Good) (and its international/global siblings)... however there seems to be nothing as straightforward as a list of companies there so far as I could find.  The best I could do was a [factsheet with some "top5" info](http://www.ftse.com/Analytics/FactSheets/temp/8cf8d852-004f-4253-9452-c3431d8017dc.pdf), and some [periodic review](http://www.ftse.com/products/index-notices/Home/GetReviews/ALL?productTitle=All%20Reviews) documents just listing differential changes ([example](http://www.ftse.com/products/index-notices/home/getnotice/?id=2255395))... but nothing with an actual list before or after those changes.

So: What are the companies included in the FTSE4Good UK 50?  (And if anyone can provide the information, where did you get it?)

Comment: http://www.ftse.com/products/indices/values-constituents and http://www.ftse.com/analytics/factsheets/Home/ConstituentsWeights  Not complete but something. Nothing on the FT website too.

Comment: @DumbCoder: looks promising but the "FTSE4Good UK 50" link on that page takes me to some factsheet about some China index!  FWIW I've used their "Contact Us" to report it as a broken link.

Comment: They did mention in one of the 2 links that they print in arrears, so I am not sure they update their website so regularly. Probably they churn companies very frequently. I was surprised the constituents not being present on FT either( I have premium subscription so can access everything).

Comment: @timday They seem to have fixed the link: it currently points to https://www.ftse.com/analytics/factsheets/Home/DownloadConstituentsWeights/?indexdetails=4UK5 (PDF) which seems to be what you want.

Comment: @TripeHound Nice find.  Thanks for chasing up this old question... if you can put an answer up with that in the next few days I'll accept it, else I can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page [Constituents & Weights](https://www.ftserussell.com/analytics/factsheets/Home/ConstituentsWeights)<sup>**1**</sup> on the FTSE Russel<sup>**2**</sup> website contains links to PDFs showing the constituents and weights for a large number of indices.  The entry for the **FTSE4Good UK50** index is towards the bottom, under ***Responsible Investment Index Series***, and currently points to [this PDF](https://research.ftserussell.com/analytics/factsheets/Home/DownloadConstituentsWeights/?indexdetails=4UK5&_ga=2.69158481.1766483044.1566544411-2075151559.1566544411).

According to the text at the top of the page:

> Constituents & Weights Spreadsheets are typically published within two months of the most recent review. For example, if an index is reviewed at the end of March, the post review constituents and weights will be published around the end of May.

---

Current prices of various indices are available on *The London Stock Exchange's* [Indices](https://www.londonstockexchange.com/exchange/prices-and-markets/stocks/indices/ftse-indices.html) page, with individual pages for each index, e.g. [FTSE 100](https://www.londonstockexchange.com/exchange/prices-and-markets/stocks/indices/summary/summary-indices.html?index=UKX) and [FTSE4Good UK Index](https://www.londonstockexchange.com/exchange/prices-and-markets/stocks/indices/ethic-indices/summary.html?index=I:4GUK). However, as noted in the question, while the *FTSE 100* page has a tab [specifically for its constituents](https://www.londonstockexchange.com/exchange/prices-and-markets/stocks/indices/summary/summary-indices-constituents.html?index=UKX), the *FTSE4Good* page does not.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> Link originally provided by [DumbCoder](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/2001/dumbcoder) in a comment: at that time, the FTSE4Good UK50 link was apparently broken, though it is now working (August 2019).

<sup>**2**</sup> From [FTSE Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTSE_Group) on Wikipedia,  *FTSE Russel* is the trading name of *FTSE International Limited*, who provide stock market indices and associated data services, and are wholly owned by the *London Stock Exchange* (LSE).

Answer (score 0):

The FTSE4Good Index data files are available to clients of FTSE. This is a commercial service for
investors, who are their primary audience.
The list of companies in FTSE4Good is available to other stakeholders on request. Where
commercial use is to be made of the data, FTSE charges for this service.

Comment: Welcome to Personal Finance & Money! I've edited your description to remove parts that aren't relevant to answering the question. Is there a reference on the FTSE website that explains this?